# Transactional data to "from/to" table

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this which is some kind of logging.

```
sales <- data.frame(
MBR_ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
DATE = as.Date(c('2020-01-01','2020-02-01','2020-03-01','2020-01-01','2020-02-01','2020-03-01','2020-04-01','2020-04-01','2020-04-02','2020-04-03','2020-04-04')), 
PROD = c('A','B','C','A','C','A','A','A','B','C','D'))
```

and I want to count the transactions from one PROD to next PROD (based on DATE) grouped by MBR_ID.
So the result should be this

```
edges <- data.frame(
from=c("A","B","A","C","A","C"), 
to=c("B","C","C","A","A","D"), 
value=c(2,2,1,1,1,1))
```

How do I do this in R? dplyr prefered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer of `dplyr` version

```
# dplyr 1.1.0
library(dplyr) 
sales |> 
  mutate(from = PROD, to = lead(PROD), .by=MBR_ID) |> 
  filter(!is.na(to)) |> 
  summarise(value=n(),.by=c(from,to))
```

**output**

```
  from to value
1    A  B     2
2    B  C     2
3    A  C     1
4    C  A     1
5    A  A     1
6    C  D     1
```

Or an alternative with `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(sales)[,.(from = PROD, to = lead(PROD)),by=MBR_ID][!is.na(to),.(value=.N), by=.(from,to)]
```

**output**

```
     from     to   value
1:      A      B     2
2:      B      C     2
3:      A      C     1
4:      C      A     1
5:      A      A     1
6:      C      D     1
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option

```
with(
    sales,
    aggregate(
        N ~ .,
        do.call(
            rbind,
            by(
                PROD,
                MBR_ID,
                \(x) cbind(
                    setNames(
                        as.data.frame(
                            embed(x, 2)[, 2:1]
                        ),
                        c("from", "to")
                    ),
                    N = 1
                )
            )
        ),
        sum
    )
)
```

gives

```
  from to N
1    A  A 1
2    C  A 1
3    A  B 2
4    A  C 1
5    B  C 2
6    C  D 1
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest and most straightforward way I can come up with:
I used `lag` to get "to" and "from" and a little bit of filtering.

The `group_by` should use the MBR_ID? I get a different but more correct result, no?

```
> sales %>% 
    mutate(from = lag(PROD)) %>% 
    rename(to = PROD) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(from) & to != from) %>% 
    group_by(MBR_ID, to, from) %>% 
    summarise(value = n()) %>% 
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 7 × 4
  MBR_ID to    from  value
   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <int>
1      1 B     A         1
2      1 C     B         1
3      2 A     C         2
4      2 C     A         1
5      3 B     A         1
6      3 C     B         1
7      3 D     C         1
```

Comment: I don't want MBR_ID in the result